# Quartz: store job instance data

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

is there a quartz feature to store and read instance specific results with a job instance. Simplest example is a job's status (running, finished ok, finished with errors + msg). This would also mean to store a history of jobs that ran already.

I just saw examples of storing job data which is not instance specific.

Thanks,
Karsten